# PHP multiple random image calling

Tags: php, image

i am trying to call more than one image to the screen at a time from a folder, currently this PHP i have coded only calls one. Any ideas would be very much appreciated...

```
<?php


// Indicate the location of your images 
$root = '';
// use if specifying path from root
$path = 'images/';

function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
            // Checks for file formats
            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($img_dir);
    }
    return $images;
}

function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
    mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); // php 4.2+ not needed
    $num = array_rand($ar);
    return $ar[$num];
}


// Collects list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);

$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
?>
```

Comment: What's the actual question. Is something going wrong? If so, what? Is your code incomplete? If so, how? etc. etc.

Comment: Hi, Joe, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant method, but it's good start for you.

```
$imageCount = 3; // show 3 images
$img = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$imageCount; $i++){    
   $img[] = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
}
```

And now you have three random images inside your $img array. You can additionally check if you don't have the same images.

There are many ways to achieve your task, maybe introduce that functionality inside `getRandomFromArray` method?

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick repsonae, sorry im a complete newbie to PHP, would the getRandomFromArray be a beeter thing to look into other than my current technique.

Comment: You should know the algorithm before you start to code anything. Think of it like that: You have some array of pictures. How could you pick randomly X of them so they won't duplicate? Make another array where you would keep the chosen images. Now take one of the images from "images" array that isn't already inside your "chosen" array. And do that X times. Done. Now write that in any programming language you want. :) If you don't have the basics (don't know how to write if statement, loop etc.) you should start with that. And then you could continue to do that in language you want. Good luck :)